# Are DApp related services like IPFS or Swarm on-topic?

Tags: discussion, 7-questions, topic

Just came across [What is the difference between Swarm and IPFS?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2138/259) which looks like off topic to me.

> off-topic because... This question does not appear to be about
>   Ethereum, the crypto value and blockchain-based consensus network,
>   within the scope defined in the help center.

How this came related to `Ethereum, the crypto value and blockchain-based consensus network` or am i missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swarm is part of the Ethereum project itself. While I had my doubts that it is still under active development, Alex van de Sande just [confirmed on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4az0cd/ethereum_develop_diary_entry_6/d14sjrq) that Swarm still has some dedicated people working on it. This would make it on-topic.

IPFS might be a different story, while it is not officially part of Ethereum; it is frequently used in combination to build DApps. I'd say it is on-topic as long as it is used for Ethereum DApps.

Comment: I am also under the impression that `Swarm` is being discontinued since there is no news of it. Your answer makes sense as long as it being used in DApp development. 
I got confused with IPFS because its a different concept altogether for me.

Comment: I think both are on-topic and SWARM is still being actively developed. It may also optionally allow for IPFS as it's underlying layer in the future, so IPFS should remain on topic.